# Quick Selection: What's wrong?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm studying quick selection algorithm but my code does not work.

```
def qselect(li, k):
    if len(li) <= 1:
        return li

    mid = len(li) // 2
    pivot = li[mid]

    left, equal, right = [], [], []

    for number in li:
        if number < pivot:
            left.append(number)
        elif number > pivot:
            right.append(number)
        else:
            equal.append(number)

    if k < len(left):
        qselect(left, k)
        return left[k-1]
    elif k < len(left) + len(equal):
        return equal[0]
    else:
        qselect(right, k)
        return right[k - len(left) - len(equal)]

li = [2, 36, 5, 21, 8, 13, 11, 20, 5, 4, 1]
k = 8
print(qselect(li,k))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "q_median.py", line 39, in <module>
    print(qselect(li,k))
  File "q_median.py", line 30, in qselect
    qselect(right, k)
  File "q_median.py", line 31, in qselect
    return right[k - len(left) - len(equal)]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The error is 'out of index' and as far as I know, this means the given index is larger than the total length of the list.

However, when I check the length of each sub-lists,

```
len(left) = 7 
len(equal) = 1
len(right) = 3
```

So, I expected right[0] is printed.

What is wrong?

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: I thought the 8th element -- which is '13' from the original list is printed out. @l'L'l

Comment: You've defined `k` past your list index `k=8`, it should be `k=7`, since the index starts at `0`.

Comment: Well, I had a same thought but it still returns the same error

Comment: Take a look: https://repl.it/repls/SoulfulTriflingMonitor

Comment: WHAT!! Mine does not work, so I wrote a new one ... Anyway, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is that you did *not* check the lengths you claim.  The *first* thing to do for debugging this is to check the values used in the offending line:

```
else:
    qselect(right, k)
    print("right", len(right))
    print(k, len(left), len(equal), k - len(left) - len(equal)) 
    return right[k - len(left) - len(equal)]
```

Output:

```
right 1
8 1 1 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wdwickar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\ZZZ learning\so.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(qselect(li,k))
  File "C:\Users\wdwickar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\ZZZ learning\so.py", line 24, in qselect
    qselect(right, k)
  File "C:\Users\wdwickar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\ZZZ learning\so.py", line 27, in qselect
    return right[k - len(left) - len(equal)]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for further help.

Comment: Thanks! 
I contemplated your answer, but now I'm wondering  why len(right) and len(left) are 1. Do I need to add more lines to merge fragmented list?
If so, why the first condition, if k < len(left) works when I put a small number?

Comment: Don't contemplate: *trace* the execution.  Find the specific point of failure, rather than asking me for a generic design review.

Comment: Thanks! I finally modified my code! I think you give me an important lesson. I appreciate!

Comment: Yes, continuous improvement is the long-term goal.
Do remember to retire the question somehow: delete or accept and answer (even if you write one yourself).  That gives you a small reputation refund, and lets Stack Overflow archive teh question properly.